# Operator overloading inside vs outside class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What is the difference between inside and outside class overloading?

```
class A{
    public:
       bool operator==(const A *i){
         ....
         ....
       }
 };
```

vs

```
 bool operator==(const A *i , const A *j){
   ....
   .... 
 }
```

Comment: If it's possible to do it outside, then do it outside. But why would you compare to a pointer? So you want `obj1 == &obj2`? No sense.

Comment: Try using either. They don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First consider this example using your class (reformatted to a style I prefer):

```
class A
{
public:
    auto operator==( A const* p )
        -> bool
    {
        return true;        // Whatever.
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    A u{}, v{};
    A const c{};

    bool const r1 = (u == &v);  // OK but needlessly annoying.
    bool const r2 = (c == &v);  // !Will not compile. 
}
```

Here

- Since the argument is a pointer, the client code must apply `&`.
- Since the method is not `const`, objects that are `const` can not be compared.

The conventional way to do this is therefore to pass the argument by reference, and to make the method `const`:

```
class B
{
public:
    auto operator==( B const& o ) const
        -> bool
    {
        return true;        // Whatever.
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    B u{}, v{};
    B const c{};

    bool const r1 = (u == v);   // OK.
    bool const r2 = (c == v);   // OK.
}
```

If you define the comparison outside the class, like this:

```
class B
{};

auto operator==( B const& u, B const& v )
    -> bool
{
    return true;        // Whatever.
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    B u{}, v{};
    B const c{};

    bool const r1 = (u == v);   // OK.
    bool const r2 = (c == v);   // OK.
}
```

… then

- The definition guaranteed does not depend on internal implementation details of class `B`, that conceivably could change in the future.
- Also the first argument can be a value that converts implicitly to `B`.
- You can, if you want, have formal arguments of different types, where the class only appears in the second argument, like this:

```
auto operator==( int const u, B const& v )
    -> bool
{
    return true;        // Whatever.
}
```

If you choose to place these non-member operators inline inside the class definition, via the `friend` mechanism (so that they're found via ADL lookup), then you lose the first bullet point's advantage, but you then have all the code relevant for use of the class, within the class definition:

```
class B
{
public:
    friend
    auto operator==( B const& u, B const& v )
        -> bool
    {
        return true;        // Whatever.
    }

    friend
    auto operator==( int const u, B const& v )
        -> bool
    {
        return true;        // Whatever.
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    B u{}, v{};
    B const c{};

    bool const r1 = (u == v);   // OK.
    bool const r2 = (c == v);   // OK.
    bool const r3 = (42 == v);  // OK.
}
```